# Which app icon gets displayed in the App Store on-device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

My universal apps come bundled with the following icons:

```
iphone-icon@2x (114x114)
iphone-icon (57x57)
ipad-icon@2x (144x144)
ipad-icon (72x72)
```

And using iTunes connect I submit another icon:

```
iTunes-icon (1024x1024)
```

Now my question is which of these icons gets displayed on each of the following: a)iPhone on-device App Store, b)iPad on-device App Store, c)iTunes on Mac/PC?

Apple's wording implies that the `iTunes-icon` will be used for all app stores, but that begs the question why Apple would use a 1024x1024 downsampled icon on-device when designers have spent hours designing the device icons specifically for each size?

Comment: The `iTunes-icon` will appear in all versions of the app store desktop and device, it will just be down scaled where needed and the others are for the device itself. Such as the `iphone-icons` will be the ones that appear on the iPhone home screen and the `ipad-icons` will appear on the iPad. This is fully documented in the apple interface guidelines here - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 6, all App Stores show the downsampled 1024x1024 icon. You can see this with apps that have a different icon in the App Store than on the home screen (e.g. the 1Password Pro icon has a red "Pro" sash in the App Store, but not when installed). I'm not sure if it was that way on the iPhone with iOS 5, I seem to remember that it showed the actual home screen icon, but I don't have an iOS 5 device here to check.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the 1024x1024 icon is used in place of the old 512x512 icon to display the icon on desktop monitors (1024x1024 is used on retina desktop displays; scaled-down 512x512 is used on normal displays). So, this is the icon used in iTunes on your Mac/PC or in your browser.

The other icons are used as appropriate to show the icon on each respective device.

The easy test for this is not providing one of the device specific icons: you will see then a jagged icon on that device for which you did not provide the optimized icon. But if you provide it, the icon will look as it should.